# C# How to move a rectangle for a certain (+x,+y)

Tags: c#, object, animation

I'm working on a project and I want to animate a rectangle to move a certain amount of pixels each time I (for example) press a button.
ex: My rectangle is at the position (x=50,y=60). I want with a click of a button to make it move +10 y each time I press it. So with one click it would go to (50,70), with the second it would go to (50,80) and so on...

I'm working with visual studio and blend on Visual C# windows store app.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you attempted to do this? If so, could you include the code you've tried?

Comment: Not really because I don't know what the code is :/
that's why I asked..

Comment: Just imagine that there is a rectangle in blend and a button.
you make the method button click to animate the rectangle and make it move a certain pixels to either x or y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the rectangle to be in a Canvas object:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
            <Canvas Name="PointCanvas" Width="500" Height="294" Margin="9,0,6,0">
                <Rectangle x:Name="myRect" Fill="#FFF5F4F5" Height="39" Canvas.Left="170" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="89" Width="89"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    <Button Name="Move" Click="Button_Click">Move</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Add a button to the window and add a Click event:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myRect = (Rectangle)this.FindName("myRect");
        double x = Canvas.GetLeft(myRect);
        double y = Canvas.GetTop(myRect);

        Canvas.SetLeft(myRect,x+10);
        Canvas.SetTop(myRect,y);
    }
```

We can then get the x,y of the rectangle within the canvas, and each button click move it a certain amount.